# Return values from a column not included in a groupby

Tags: pandas

I have a df like so:

```
ID  R2     Var   
1   0.2    GDD
2   0.3    GDD
3   0.9    GDD
1   0.5    PRCP
2   0.1    PRCP
3   0.8    PRCP
```

and I want to find the two smallest `R2` values grouped within `Var` and see what their `ID` is.

I am using this code:

```
df.groupby(['Var'])['R2'].nsmallest(2).reset_index()
```

which gives me a dataframe with the two smallest `R2` in each group, but I want to know what their `ID` is as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set *ID* as the index axis prior to performing grouping:

```
df.set_index('ID').groupby('Var')['R2'].nsmallest(2).reset_index()
```

[image]

---

Notice `level=1` of the multi-index series produced after grouping gives you the order in which the index axis appears. So using this knowledge, you could also `reindex` based on those obtained values as shown:

```
df.reindex(df.groupby('Var')['R2'].nsmallest(2).index.get_level_values(1)
          ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the first option is much more intuitive and cleaner to me, but nice to know about the second as well